# "Cannot access [abstract method] in [abstract parent]"

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider this code

```java
public interface ExpectationTester {
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException;
}
```

```java
public abstract class AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester implements ExpectationTester {
    protected final String serializedResponseBody;
    protected final String expectedCommentText;
    protected final int expectedQuestionId;
    protected final int expectedOwnerId;
    protected final String expectedOwnerUsername;
    protected final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    protected AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester(Builder builder) {
        this.serializedResponseBody = builder.serializedResponseBody;
        this.expectedOwnerId = builder.expectedOwnerId;
        this.expectedOwnerUsername = builder.expectedOwnerUsername;
        this.expectedQuestionId = builder.expectedQuestionId;
        this.expectedCommentText = builder.expectedCommentText;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
    public abstract void test() throws JsonProcessingException;
    protected abstract static class Builder {
        protected final String serializedResponseBody;
        protected String expectedCommentText = "text";
        protected int expectedQuestionId = 1;
        protected int expectedOwnerId = 1;
        protected String expectedOwnerUsername = "user";
        protected Builder(MockHttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            this.serializedResponseBody = response.getContentAsString();
        }
        public Builder setExpectedOwnerUsername(String expectedOwnerUsername) {
            this.expectedOwnerUsername = expectedOwnerUsername;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder setExpectedOwnerId(int expectedOwnerId) {
            this.expectedOwnerId = expectedOwnerId;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder setExpectedQuestionId(int expectedQuestionId) {
            this.expectedQuestionId = expectedQuestionId;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder setExpectedCommentText(String expectedCommentText) {
            this.expectedCommentText = expectedCommentText;
            return this;
        }
        public abstract AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester build();
    }
}
```

```java
// one of the two descendants
public class GetCommentExpectationTester extends AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester {
    public GetCommentExpectationTester(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }
    @Override
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Data<QuestionCommentResponseDto> deserializedResponseBody =
                objectMapper.readValue(serializedResponseBody, Data.class);
        assertNotNull(deserializedResponseBody.getData());
        QuestionCommentResponseDto dto = deserializedResponseBody.getData();
        assertEquals(expectedQuestionId, dto.getQuestionId());
        assertEquals(expectedCommentText, dto.getText());
        assertNotNull(dto.getOwner());

        AccountResponseDto owner = dto.getOwner();
        assertEquals(expectedOwnerId, owner.getId());
        assertEquals(expectedOwnerUsername, owner.getUsername());
    }
    public static class Builder extends AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester.Builder {
        public Builder(MockHttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            super(response);
        }
        @Override
        public GetCommentExpectationTester build() {
            return new GetCommentExpectationTester(this);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Test
    @Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "GetCommentTest/before.sql")
    @Sql(executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "GetCommentTest/after.sql")
    public void getCommentTest() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URI + 1)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();

        expectationTester = new GetCommentExpectationTester.Builder(response)
                .setExpectedOwnerUsername("mickey")
                .build(); // this line is problematic

        expectationTester.test();
    }
```

As you can see, I use a simple hierarchy to reduce code duplication in my test methods. The base parent class has a nested abstract builder that, in turn, has an abstract `build()` method. The problem is I can't call it, and the error message in not very informative to me

**Why can't I call the `build()` method inherited from the abstract parent?**

> Cannot access 'build()' in 'stack.overflow.controller.expectationTesters.AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester.Builder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `Builder` in the abstract parent is `protected`. As a result, it is not accessible by classes that do not extend it, including your test class. I suggest you change the `protected` modifer to `public`. It resolves the issue

```java
public abstract class AbstractGetCommentExpectationTester implements ExpectationTester {
// ...
public abstract static class Builder {
```